# Adding stylesheet to xml with javascript not displaying correctly or at all

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, epub

After a year of using stackoverflow I decided to join, but of course due to the fact that after a day of struggling I am stuck.

My Problem: I am using javascript to build a document made of xml document, and stylesheet. This works well, (In Firefox, not at all in IE) for two of my cases but not the third.

javascript========================================

```
function GetBookInfo(object)
{
    try
    {
        var xmlCont=loadXMLDoc("files/books/"+object.id+"/META-INF/container.xml");
        opfFile=xmlCont.getElementsByTagName("container")[0].getElementsByTagName("rootfiles")[0].getElementsByTagName("rootfile")[0].getAttribute("full-path");        
        xmlCont=loadXMLDoc("files/books/"+object.id+"/"+opfFile);
        xsl=loadXMLDoc("files/content.xsl");         
        displayXML(xmlCont, xsl, object.id);
    }
    catch (EventException)
    {
        alert(EventException.toString());
    }
}

function displayXML(xmlIn, xslIn, place)
{
    // code for IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
            ex=xmlIn.transformNode(xslIn);
            document.getElementById(place).innerHTML=ex;
    }
    // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else 
        if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
    {
            xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
            xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslIn);
            resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlIn,document);     
            document.getElementById(place).appendChild(resultDocument);
    }
}

function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    }
        try
        {
            xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
            xhttp.send("");
            return xhttp.responseXML;
        }
        catch (EventException)
        {
            alert("Could not open: " +dname);
        } 
}
```

javascript========================================
xsl==============================================

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/package"> 
        <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="METADATA">
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <div id="title">
                        <xsl:value-of select='metadata/dc:title'/>
                    </div> 
                    <br />                       
                    <div id="creator">
                        <xsl:value-of select='metadata/dc:creator'/>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div id="publisher">
                        <xsl:value-of select='metadata/dc:publisher'/>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div id="language">
                        <xsl:value-of select='metadata/dc:language'/>
                    </div>
                    <br />                        
                    <div id="rights">
                        <xsl:value-of select='metadata/dc:rights'/>
                    </div>                        
                    <br />
                    <div id="subject">
                        <xsl:value-of select='metadata/dc:subject'/>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div id="publicationDate">
                        <xsl:value-of select='metadata/dc:date[@opf:event="publication"]'/>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div id="conversionDate">
                        <xsl:value-of select='metadata/dc:date[@opf:event="conversion"]'/>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div id="source">
                        <xsl:value-of select='metadata/dc:source'/>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </div>                

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

xsl==============================================

The xml file is a typical opf file found in an epub folder.
opf(standard xml)==================================================

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<package xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" version="2.0" unique-identifier="id">
  <metadata>
    <dc:rights>Public domain in the USA.</dc:rights>
    <dc:identifier id="id" opf:scheme="URI">http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/1065</dc:identifier>
    <dc:creator opf:file-as="Poe, Edgar Allan">Edgar Allan Poe</dc:creator>
    <dc:title>The Raven</dc:title>
    <dc:language xsi:type="dcterms:RFC4646">en</dc:language>
    <dc:subject>Poetry, English</dc:subject>
    <dc:date opf:event="publication">1997-10-01</dc:date>
    <dc:date opf:event="conversion">2010-06-08T08:59:43.376234+00:00</dc:date>
    <dc:source>http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1065/1065-h/1065-h.htm</dc:source>
    <meta content="item5" name="cover"/>
  </metadata>
  <manifest>
    <item href="pgepub.css" id="item1" media-type="text/css"/>
    <item href="0.css" id="item2" media-type="text/css"/>
    <item href="1.css" id="item3" media-type="text/css"/>
    <!--Chunk: size=31062-->
    <item href="www.gutenberg.org@files@1065@1065-h@1065-h-0.htm" id="item4" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    <item href="cover.jpg" id="item5" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
    <item href="toc.ncx" id="ncx" media-type="application/x-dtbncx+xml"/>
  </manifest>
  <spine toc="ncx">
    <itemref idref="item4" linear="yes"/>
  </spine>
</package>
```

opf(standard xml)==================================================

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
PS: If anyone knows why IE doens't display any of xsl created documents with error:
 "The stylesheet does not contain a document element.  The stylesheet may be empty, or it may not be a well-formed XML document."
it would also help, thanks.

Comment: Consider to show a sample of the XML for which the code fails. And what does the error console of Firefox show when the code fails? I would strongly suggest to change the code to use feature checking for the feature you want to use e.g. `if (typeof XSLTProcessor != 'undefined') { /* now use XSLTProcessor here */ }` instead of checking for an unrelated feature like `document.implementation`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen
The first error I get with my try catch is this from firefox:
"[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIXSLTProcessor.importStylesheet]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/files/options.js :: displayXML :: line 54"  data: no]"
Line 54 being: "xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslIn);"

Comment: I tested now with a random opf file, by manualy adding the link to the style sheet, and then opening the opf file in a web browser, it says in Firefox: "Error loading stylesheet: An unknown error has occurred ()" I have scanned through my style sheet with no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Your stylesheet is failing because it is invalid. It uses the `dc:` and `opf:` namespaces in several places, but does not declare them. To fix this, change the opening `xsl:stylesheet` tag to contain the necessary namespace declarations. Since the source XML uses a default namespace, you will need to use namespaces for those nodes as well. I've also modified your XSLT to show how it can be made more succinct:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
  <xsl:template match="opf:package">
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="opf:metadata" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="opf:metadata">
    <div id="METADATA">
      <p>Hello</p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select='dc:title'/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select='dc:creator'/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select='dc:publisher'/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select='dc:language'/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select='dc:rights'/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select='dc:subject'/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select='dc:date[@opf:event="publication"]'>
        <xsl:with-param name='id' select='"publicationDate"' />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:apply-templates select='dc:date[@opf:event="conversion"]'>
        <xsl:with-param name='id' select='"conversionDate"' />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:apply-templates select='dc:source'/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match='opf:metadata/*'>
    <xsl:param name='id' select='local-name()' />

    <div id='{$id}'>
      <xsl:value-of select='.'/>
    </div>
    <br />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I also found that when starting my stylesheet with '<xsl:template match="/package">' it displays all the data within the opf's metadata no matter what my stylesheet has within that template.
Now my problem is, when I take package away, it doesn't display the title as I wish in this case '<h1>T<xsl:value-of select='/package/metadata/dc:title' />T</h1>' all it displays is "TT" what could be the issue now, something with dc, I suppose, but what?

Comment: As Martin indicates in his answer, since your source XML uses a default namespace, you need to use a namespace in the XPaths. In this case, that default namespace turns out to be the same as the `opf` namespace, so that can be used for your `package` and `metadata` nodes as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the namespaces including the default namespace into account when writing path expressions in your XSLT code.

So your code should be

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  exclude-result-prefixes="opf dc">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/opf:package"> 
                <div id="METADATA">
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <div id="title">
                        <xsl:value-of select='opf:metadata/dc:title'/>
                    </div> 
                    <br />                       
                    <div id="creator">
                        <xsl:value-of select='opf:metadata/dc:creator'/>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div id="publisher">
                        <xsl:value-of select='opf:metadata/dc:publisher'/>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div id="language">
                        <xsl:value-of select='opf:metadata/dc:language'/>
                    </div>
                    <br />                        
                    <div id="rights">
                        <xsl:value-of select='opf:metadata/dc:rights'/>
                    </div>                        
                    <br />
                    <div id="subject">
                        <xsl:value-of select='opf:metadata/dc:subject'/>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div id="publicationDate">
                        <xsl:value-of select='opf:metadata/dc:date[@opf:event="publication"]'/>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div id="conversionDate">
                        <xsl:value-of select='opf:metadata/dc:date[@opf:event="conversion"]'/>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div id="source">
                        <xsl:value-of select='opf:metadata/dc:source'/>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </div>                

    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have removed the `html` and `body` elements as your Javascript code indicates you want to create a fragment of HTML to be included in an existing HTML document that already has those structural elements.